# How to clone entire VirtualBox OS to a new PC (real-hardware)?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, clone

The situation is; I am running a web server (`Ubuntu 10.10 server`) on `virtualbox v.4` inside `Ubuntu 10.10 Desktop` and now I want to clone entire web server on my brand new PC. 
Please help me with this, how do I do it?

Thanks!

---

I found a possible solution here: http://www.turnkeylinux.org/blog/convert-vm-iso

Comment: You mean virtual to physical (V2P)?

Comment: Yes, something like that but even easer way like creating bootable DVD of Virtual OS, something like recovery DVD..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using converttoraw feature of virtual box and DD.

See: http://techokarma.blogspot.com/2008/10/v2p-virtual-to-physical-for-virtualbox.html

This assumes you have a reasonable knowledge of linux.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Yes, v2p may work if I copy raw into a attached HDD. But what if I need to clone into a new laptop which has no OS installed? Do you think will it work if I copy raw into a USB pendrive then attach with new laptop and boot from Live-CD then do dd??

Comment: @Himalay, Not sure about that.

Answer (score 6):

Quick trick to copy over a network: use linux netcat (nc).  Using this method you do not have to convert to a raw image as dd will copy literally everything from the source drive.

Use your choice of linux live discs to boot both the physical machine and virtual machine, make sure both have network access and write down the IP addresses of both.  Switch to root (sudo su).  Find out what your drive paths are using fdisk -l

On the destination machine:

```
nc -l 10000 | dd of=/dev/sda bs=64
```

Command syntax:

```
nc -l <port#> | dd of=<destination drive> bs=<size in bytes>
```

Block size (bs) can be whatever you want, I try to keep it fairly small.

On the source virtual machine:

```
dd if=/dev/sda bs=64 | nc 192.168.0.100 10000
```

Command Syntax:

```
dd if=<source drive> bs=<size in bytes> | nc <destination ip> <destination port#>
```

Block size (bs) at the source and destination must match.  I always set the destination machine up to reduce sending errors.  There is no progress bar, just wait for the bash prompt to return and you are good to go.  Remove the live discs and reboot.

Comment: You can actually get the progress of dd by running `kill -USR1 $PIDOfDD` or watching the transfer over time by running `watch -n 10 kill -USR1 $PIDOfDD` [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/215505/how-do-you-monitor-the-progress-of-dd)